# CDF Player: MathKernel.exe uses a lot of memory

Tags: cdf-format

When I run this CDF document http://x6174x.blogspot.pt/2013/04/bankroll-growth-simulator.html on my desktop, each time I press "Run again" the Task Manager shows that the MathKernel.exe process associated with the CDF player uses increasingly more RAM.

However if I try it on a laptop with the same OS (Win 7 Ultimate) the memory usage remains more or less constant.  What could be wrong with the first CDF Player?  I tried to reinstall it but the problem persists.  I should add that the first computer has Mathematica 9 installed but the laptop has only the CDF Player.

Could this be some interaction between the CDF player and Mathematica? Even if I have Mathematica closed when I run the CDF document it will show a Mathematica.exe process running.

Thanks.